# JS event OnClick not found

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, vba

There is this Word(Toto) (in a Table ) when I click on it,it adds two more lignes and i need those, so i figured its a Onclick event But there is nothing not even a JS thing Weird No , (When i click the code changes )
Here is the Html Code :

BEFORE I CLICK :

```
<td class="pcrLibelle data plier">
    <span name="codedefaut">Toto</span> 
    <span name="code" style="display:none;">Toto </span> 
</td>
```

AFTER I CLICK :

```
 <td class="pcrLibelle data deplier">
     <span name="codedefaut">Toto</span> 
     <span name="code" style="display:none;">Toto</span>
</td>
```

And those two lignes when the become Visible there Class changes like this:

Before I click :

```
<tr class="Toto1 hide"... > </tr>
<tr class="Toto2 hide ... > </tr>
```

After i click :

```
<tr class="Toto1 display"... > </tr>
<tr class="Toto2 display"... > </tr>
```

Why i do this ?

I need to execute the "Onclick" event if there is any to change the value of one of those two lignes; i tried to change it directly without the clicking on "Toto" It doesnt work .
I did it in VBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
onClick="function()" - is available in core javascript
```

jQuery is a JavaScript library consist of many predefined function as there is no **onclick** - instead of this there is **click** event even there is **on** in jQuery.

```
$("element").click(function(){
   // Your code
})

Alternative 

$("element").on('click', function(){
  // your code
})
```

You will use any one among this

Comment: Yep its a .click Thank you

Comment: I found that "jQuery(".pcrLibelle").click(function()" this thing changes the <tr>'s class, normally to execut a function i call it by her name but now there is no name !! i tried 
     oBrowser.document.parentWindow.execScript "jQuery(".pcrLibelle").click(function()", "javascript" it didnt work

Comment: just put your code in js Fiddle , its not tough - will solve it

Comment: you can even use
$("tr").on("click", function(){
  var selected_tr = $(this);
  
  // Now tr on which you have clicked is 'selected_tr'
})

Comment: You sure about this ?because i need to do With Vba language

Comment: Alright it works Thank you all , i didnt use the JS i took all <TD> and used a Counter to click on the right one , its dumb but it works so its not dumb

Comment: Nevermind i used `.click` in vba and it worked Thank you evryOne